# promisifying an already promisified function with promisifyAll

Tags: node.js, promise, bluebird

According to Bluebird documentation about [promisification](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html#promisification):

> If the object already has a promisified version of the method, it will be skipped.

In fact, the `promisifyAll()` also creates an `Async` version of an already promisified function, which is expected to be:

> idempotent in the sense that promisified functions are instantly returned back.

As pointed in Issue [Idempotent promisify #159](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/159)

So in the following example, I was expecting that both `obj.foo()` and `obj.fooAsync()` have the same result.

```
let obj = {
    foo: function(){
        return Promise.resolve('I am foo!!!')
    }
}
obj = Promise.promisifyAll(obj)
obj.foo().then(msg => console.log(msg))      // > I am foo
obj.fooAsync().then(msg => console.log(msg)) // prints nothing
```

Which part am I misunderstanding?

Running example [here](https://repl.it/IEt5/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which part am I misunderstanding?

That your `foo` function would be promisified already. It's not - it just returns a promise. And as Petka [points out](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/issues/159#issuecomment-38348877), "*It is impossible to tell in code if some function is a promise returning function.*" (at least in the general sense, there are *some* functions for which we can tell).

Being "promisified", especially in the context of an [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) `Promise.promisify` function, refers to a function that is the result of a `Promise.promisify` call (or was created through `Promise.promisifyAll`). It's about [this part of the code](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/3746b7eca90dd8b11af73db5d30cf46d7dd90f9b/src/promisify.js#L284-L286) that [checks whether the function is tagged as being bluebird-created](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/3746b7eca90dd8b11af73db5d30cf46d7dd90f9b/src/promisify.js#L35-L42).

A better demonstration:

```
const obj = {
    foo(callback) {
        callback(null, 'I am foo!!!')
    }
};
Promise.promisifyAll(obj);
obj.fooAsync().then(console.log) // > I am foo
// so far so good

Promise.promisifyAll(obj);
console.assert(typeof obj.fooAsyncAsync == "undefined"); // it didn't promisify again
console.assert(obj.fooAsync === Promise.promisify(obj.fooAsync));
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer, but I did spot something...not sure what it means, but thought I'd share:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');

const obj = {
    foo: () => {
        return new Promise((resolve)=> {
            resolve('Hello!!!');
        });
    }
};

const new_obj = Promise.promisifyAll(obj);
console.log(new_obj.foo());
console.log(new_obj.fooAsync());
console.log(new_obj);
```

Returns:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 33554432,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: 'Hello!!!',
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
Promise {
  _bitField: 134217728,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
{ foo: [Function: foo], fooAsync: [Function: ret] }
```

Questions:

- Why are both `_fulfillmentHandler0: undefined`?
- Why is the `_rejectionHandler0` of `foo` the return of `'Hello!!!'` that we are expecting from `_fulfillmentHandler0`?
- Why is `foo: [Function: foo]` and `fooAsync: [Function: ret]`?

Comment: Don't read anything into the internal representation of the Bluebird promise. It's all kind of implementation-dependent magic.